# Unexpected output in my simple class function. Why?

Tags: c++, class

**This is the assignment  which I’m trying to do:**

Define a PayRoll class  that has data members for an employee’s hourly pay rate (an integer , representing cents) and number of hours worked (also an integer ). The class  provides two member functions, setRate and setHours that assign  the value  of their parameter  to the appropriate data member. The class  provides a third member function, getPay, that returns weekly gross pay (in cents), computed as follows: hours times rate for the first 35 hours plus hours times rate times one and a half for any hours past 35.

**Expected Output:**

```
With•rate•set•to•150•and•hours•set•to•20•getPay•returns•3000
With•rate•set•to•230•and•hours•set•to•15•getPay•returns•3450
With•rate•set•to•975•and•hours•set•to•33•getPay•returns•32175
With•rate•set•to•1000•and•hours•set•to•35•getPay•returns•35000
With•rate•set•to•1000•and•hours•set•to•36•getPay•returns•36500
With•rate•set•to•850•and•hours•set•to•40•getPay•returns•36125
```

**Actual Output:**

```
With•rate•set•to•150•and•hours•set•to•20•getPay•returns•3000
With•rate•set•to•230•and•hours•set•to•15•getPay•returns•3450
With•rate•set•to•975•and•hours•set•to•33•getPay•returns•32175
With•rate•set•to•1000•and•hours•set•to•35•getPay•returns•35000
With•rate•set•to•1000•and•hours•set•to•36•getPay•returns•54000
With•rate•set•to•850•and•hours•set•to•40•getPay•returns•51000
```

As you can see, the last two actual outputs are not the same as the expected outputs. I've no clue why. That's my problem.

**My code:**

```
class PayRoll
{
private:
    int hourlyPayRate;
    int hoursWorked;
public:
    void setRate (int iRate){
        hourlyPayRate = iRate;
    }
    void setHours (int iHours) {
        hoursWorked = iHours;
    }
    int getPay() {
        if (hoursWorked <= 35)
            return hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
        else if (hoursWorked > 35)
            return hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate * 1.5; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Read the assignment description carefully!

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should spend more time trying to understand what you need to do rather then running around trying to get a quick answer on the internet.

Comment: @iMoses I honestly spent over two hours on this so far. :(

Comment: Well, did you do what I suggested? If so, you'll see the problem.

Comment: @kec Yeah, I did. Thank you. Is there a way to answer my own question?

Comment: Read your task, you're supposed to calculate the rate differently for overtime, right now you're calculating the overtime rate for all the hours, and not just the hours starting from the 36th hour. standard rate - first 35 hours, overtime rate - every additional hour.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
int getPay() {
    if (hoursWorked <= 35) 
        return hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
    else if (hoursWorked > 35)
        // Hourly rate for the first 35 hours and 1.5 time for 
        // the remaining = (hours -35)
        return (35 * hourlyPayRate ) + ((hoursWorked-35) * (hourlyPayRate * 1.5)); 
}
```